# Cefsharp Smooth Scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, scroll, cefsharp

So I wanted to transfer my Winforms Project into Wpf, it works all good except for one thing. I doesn´t scroll smooth. Now it scroll directly to the position not with a "transition". I searched for it, but could not find any solution. As you can see I tried it with CefCommandLineArgs but it is not working, but when I use disable-smooth-scrolling in my Winforms Project then it has the same scroll as in the Wpf Project. Is there a CommandArg to enable smooth-scroll?

```
        InitializeComponent();
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
        settings.BackgroundColor = ColorToUInt(Color.FromRgb(31, 31, 31));
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--disable-threaded-scrolling", "1");
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-threaded-scrolling", "1");
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-features", "AsyncWheelEvents,TouchpadAndWheelScrollLatching");
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://example.com");
        browser.MenuHandler = new MyHandler();
        browser.RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler();
        var cookie = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
        Cookie app = new Cookie();
        app.Name = "Appdetection";
        app.Value = "True";
        Cookie version = new Cookie();
        app.Name = "Version";
        app.Value = "1.0";
        cookie.SetCookieAsync("https://example.com", app);
        cookie.SetCookieAsync("https://example.com", version);
        Panel.Children.Add(browser);
```

Comment: What doesn't scroll smooth?  When you click the scrollbar up/down? When you hold the middle button and drag? When you scroll the mousewheel?  When you hold down the cursor keys?

Comment: What version are you using? It's not clear what you mean exactly,  please review and try to clarify.

Comment: When I use the mousewheel IT scroll directly to the next point in wpf, in winform IT Scrolls also to the Point but with a Transition.

Comment: I use Version 81.3.100!

Comment: How does it behave if you remove the command line args you've specified?  From memory tge TouchpadAndWheelScrollLatching option was removed from chromium. disable-features should be avoided unless you know exactly what you are doing, the recommendation to set it was likely from a much older version.

Comment: How does the https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample behave?

Comment: So if I remove it, the problem stays.

Comment: Please test with the minimal example. Please be clearer in your answers,  just saying you removed something without saying what isn't clear.

Comment: Yes, in the Minimal Example it`s the same problem

Comment: Last time I checked it was scrolling fine,  there are obviously hardware and software variances that can influence the behaviour. You can try https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ if that doesn't work work then it's likely 
 supported on your system.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot belive I am the only one with this problem. Do you have any other ideas? I have uploaded a Youtube-Video where you can clearly see the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdkajT7CxjU

Comment: I tested it on my laptop and I have the same problem.